Could dark matter be responsible for periodic comet impacts on Earth?
I've been reading a fascinating paper by Lisa Randall and Matthew Reece on the potential role of dark matter in triggering periodic comet impacts on Earth, possibly linked to mass extinctions. The paper suggests that a "dark disk" within the galactic plane could periodically enhance gravitational perturbations, leading to increased comet showers from the Oort cloud.
The authors argue that as the Solar System oscillates through this dark disk, the resulting tidal forces could disrupt the Oort cloud, sending more comets into the inner Solar System, which then might collide with Earth. They base their model on the idea that a fraction of dark matter could cool and form a disk-like structure, which would have a higher density and could explain a 35 million-year periodicity in large impact events.
Could someone explain in more detail how the tidal forces from a dark matter disk might lead to this periodic comet activity? Specifically, how does the density and scale height of the dark disk influence the frequency and intensity of these comet showers?

The Galactic tidal acceleration on the Oort cloud is roughly the gradient of the Galactic gravitational field multiplied by the radius of the Oort cloud around the Sun. The tidal acceleration perturbs the orbits of icy Oort cloud bodies and is likely responsible for disrupting them from an initial disc-like morphology, produced by scattering from the inner Solar System, into a more spherical distribution with high eccentricities. The idea would be that every time the Solar System passes through the Galactic plane, an enhanced tidal field pulls Oort cloud bodies out into even more eccentric orbits that allow them to plunge into the inner Solar System some tens of thousands of years later.
In a simple model, the Sun is embedded in a symmetric, uniform disc of matter with $\rho = \rho_0\exp(-|z|/z_0)$, with $|z|$ the distance from the Galactic plane and $z_0$ a scale height. Gauss's law can be used to estimate the vertical component of the gravitational field
$$2\pi a^2 g_z = -8\pi G \int_{0}^{z} \pi a^2 \rho_0 \exp(-|z'|/z_0)\ dz'\ , $$
$$ g_z = 4\pi G \rho_0 z_0 [\exp(-|z'|/z)]^{z}_{0}\ , $$
$$ g_z = -4\pi G \rho_0 z_0[1 - \exp(-|z|/z_0)]\ .$$
If the Oort cloud has a characteristic radius $r$, then the tidal acceleration due the Galactic disc is
$$ g_{\rm tide}\simeq \frac{\partial g_z}{\partial z}r = -4\pi G \rho_0 \exp(-|z|/z_0)r$$
and is maximised when $z=0$ and is proportional to the local mass density of the disc.
The scale height is indirectly relevant because the total mass of the disc, which is presumably a fixed quantity, constrained by the motions of stars, is proportional to $\rho_0 z_0$. Thus $\rho_0$, and hence $g_{\rm tide}$, would be larger if $z_0$ were smaller. Also, any periodic increase in $g_{\rm tide}$ would become more significant as $z_0$ became much less than the Solar System's $\sim 100$ pc excursions above and below the Galactic plane.
In the paper you reference, the model is more complex. The mass distribution is a combination of an almost uniform (over the distances travelled by the Sun) baryonic disc and a much thinner (5 pc) dark matter disk, which only contributes 20% of the total disc mass. The narrowness of the dark matter disc leads to a sharp spike in the tidal acceleration as the Sun passes through the plane and an enhanced periodicity in comet infall over what would be expected from the baryonic disc alone.
